# Updating post using custom MVC framework

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller

Good day,

Could someone please assist as I am trying to update the posts table using a custom MVC framework. After submitting the update form, I receive the error message:

> 'Undefined property: App\Controllers\Posts::$post'

that refers to this line in the Controller:

```
if ($this->post->updatePost($_POST)) {
```

Please find the code below:

View:

```
{% block footer %}

    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var postId = '{{ post.id }}';       
        });
    </script>


{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>Update Post</h1>

    <form method="post" id="formPost" action="/posts/update">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputTitle">Title</label>
            <input id="inputTitle" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ post.title }}" required class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputDescription">Description</label>
            <input id="inputDescription" name="description" placeholder="Description" value="{{ post.descriptionl }}" required class="form-control" />
        </div>
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        <a href="/post/show">Cancel</a>

    </form>
```

Controller:

```
   /**
     * Show the form for editing the post
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function editAction()
    {
        View::renderTemplate('Posts/edit.html', [
        

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the post
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateAction()
    {     
        
        if ($this->post->updatePost($_POST)) {         
            
            Flash::addMessage('Changes saved');

            $this->redirect('/Posts/index');

        } else {

            View::renderTemplate('Posts/edit.html', [
                $this->post = Posts::findByID($id)
            ]);

        }
    }
```

Model:

```
        public static function findByID($id)
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts
                    WHERE id = :id';
         
            $db = static::getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());
         
            $stmt->execute();
         
            return $stmt->fetch();
        }
/**
     * Update the user's Post
     *
     * @param array $data Data from the edit post form
     *
     * @return boolean  True if the data was updated, false otherwise
     */
    public function updateProfile($data)
    {
        $this->name = $data['title'];
        $this->email = $data['description'];

      
        $this->validate();

        if (empty($this->errors)) {

            $sql = 'UPDATE posts
                    SET title = :title,
                        description = :description';

            $sql .= "\nWHERE id = :id";


            $db = static::getDB();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':title', $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':description', $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':id', $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);   

            return $stmt->execute();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: And this custom framework of yours, which one would it be? Reminds me of Slim, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @El_Vanja sorry for only replying now. The problem with updating of the the posts has been resolved, thank you (it is a framework from Dave Hollingworth).